# How to use 2D array in selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Hi i want to use 2D array in my code.
I am using that in loop to point element to each other. 
I am trying 2D arrays,
a[i]=b[j]
in array a[i] i am going to store some xpath and in another array b[j] i want to store their values.i am using ruby plus selenium.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Instead of using 2D array, you can use "Hash" for better programming.
- This is the sample example of my code :

`some_hash_name = { "xpath 1" => "value 1","xpath 2" => "value 2" }`

`some_hash_name.each do |path,value|`

`some_hash_name.select_by(:text, "#{path}")`

`$driver.find_element(:xpath,"//tbody/tr[3]/select/option[#{value}]").click`

In this way you can use "hash" in Ruby.

- Hope this will help you.

Cheers!!!